# How join two collections between Objects "_id" in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

regards, I am trying to merge two collections.

- Products
- Categories

The point is that its only relationship is the ObjectId of the corresponding document, see:

**PRODUCT COLLECTION**

```
{
    "_id": Object(607a858c2db9a42d1870270f),
    "code":"CODLV001",
    "name":"Product Name",
    "category":"607a63e5778bf40cac75d863",
    "tax":"0",
    "saleValue":"0",
    "status":true
}
```

**CATEGORY COLLECTION**

```
{
    "_id": Object(607a63bf06e84e5240d377de),
    "name": "Diversey Care",
    "status": true
},
{
    "_id": Object(607a63e5778bf40cac75d863),
    "name": "Sani Tisu Profesional",
    "status": true
}
```

**WHAT I'M DOING**

```
.collection(collection)
        .aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'categories',
              localField: 'products.category',
              foreignField: 'categories._id',
              as: 'category',
            },
          },
        ])
        .toArray();
```

**WHAT AM I GETTING?**

```
{
    _id: 607a858c2db9a42d1870270f,
    code: 'CODLV001',
    name: 'Product Name',
    category: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    tax: '0',
    saleValue: '0'
  }
```

**WHAT I EXPECT?**

```
{
        _id: 607a858c2db9a42d1870270f,
        code: 'CODLV001',
        name: 'Product Name',
        category: [ [Object] ], // or every field from category collection without an array object
        tax: '0',
        saleValue: '0'
      }
```

But, if I use this way, the ***category field*** is an empty array

```
{
$lookup: {
          from: 'categories',
          localField: 'category',
          foreignField: '_id', 
          as: 'category', 
        },
      },
```

So, what i'm doing wrong (just in case I'm new in the wolrd of MongoDB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few fixes in your query,

- `products` collection field `category` is string type and `categories` field `_id` is objectId type so we need to convert it to objectId using `$toObjectId`
- `$lookup`, pass `localField` as `category` and pass `foreignField` as `_id`, there is no need to concat collection name

```
.collection(collection).aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      category: {
        $toObjectId: "$category"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      localField: "category",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "category"
    }
  }
]).toArray();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/drcNXXn6f-X)